# Iterate through DataFrame and assign step number to rows with identical ids

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to iterate through a Pandas dataframe, and add a **new column** called "step number".

There are many different enquiry_ids, and I'd like to **assign the first entry under a new enquiry_id to have a "step number" of 1**, and then **if the next row is of the same** enquiry id, for that to have a step number of **2**, etc.

And then when there's a **new enquiry_id**, this will **reset to step number of 1**.

I have no clue how to pull this off though, any ideas?

Thank you!

Below is a screenshot showing the dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Do they have to be consecutive or just part of a group? The later is `df.groupby('enquiry_id').cumcount() + 1`... - does that maybe do  what you want?

Comment: That's fantastic, works perfectly thank you! They're already ordered by date so the cumcount does the job :D

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of *iloc* and *for* loops if you want. Although I think it might increase the time complexity.

```
data= {"Enq_id":[100,101,100,102,101,100],
      "action_date":["012020","022020","032020","042020","052020","062020"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["count"]=0

for j in range(len(df.Enq_id)):
    n = df.Enq_id[j]
    c=1
    for i in range(len(df.Enq_id)):
        if (df.Enq_id[i]==n):
            df.iloc[i,2]=c
            c=c+1
```

[image]